# Implementing Event Tracking with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have dadded Universal Analytics to Google Tag Manager with it's default settings. Currently I have below code in the user registration page:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Account Events', 'Create Account', 'Create new account ']);
```

How can I convert this to 'DataLayer.push' ? Is there any configuration changes needed in GTM side? Please let me know.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this which happens when the account creation form is successfully submitted:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'account created',
   'cat': 'Account Events',
   'act': 'Create Account',
   'lab': 'Create new account'
})
```

and then in GTM, you would need to create the event tag with the respective macros for the category, action, and label.

The event tag would fire on this rule:

```
{{event}} equals "account created"
```